# How to start proving $A \times B \times C \ne (A \times B) \times C$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

This is a problem from *Discrete Mathematics and its Applications*:

> 39. Explain why $A \times B \times C$ and $(A \times B) \times C$ are not the same.

I understand the process behind the Cartesian product of two sets:

> Let $A$ and $B$ be sets. The *Cartesian Product* of $A$ and $B$, denoted by $A \times B$, is the set of all ordered pairs $(a,b)$, where $a \in A$ and $b \in B$. Hence,
>
> $$A \times B = \{(a,b)\mid a \in A \land b \in B\}.$$

You are forming a set of all the possible ordered pairs where one element is a member of the first set and the other element is a member of the other set.

How would you start this proof or explanation? To me these should be the same because it involves the same operation (Cartesian product). Usually when there are three expressions that are applied the same operation, you just go left to right, say 4 * 5 * 6. I don't understand how you would explain A x B x C is not equal to (A x B) x C. To me, using my last example, that's like explaining 4 * 5 * 6 is not equal to (4 * 5) *6.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You didn't give a definition for $A\times B\times C$ but it's usually defined by
$$A\times B\times C=\{(a,b,c) | a\in A, b\in B, c\in C\}$$
Now $(A\times B)\times C$ is, by definition
$$(A\times B)\times C = \{((a,b),c) | (a,b)\in A\times B, c\in C\} = \{((a,b),c) | a\in A,b\in B, c\in C\}$$
This shows you the difference: The elements are of the form $((a,b),c) \ne (a,b,c)$, but they are, in fact, in a 1-1 correspondence, wich may be the point of confusion.

---

Addendum due to comment of Asaf: An ordered pair can be written as a set:
$$(a,b) = \{a,\{a,b\}\}\\
(a,b,c) = \{a,\{a,b\},\{a,b,c\}\}\\
((a,b),c) = \{(a,b),\{(a,b),c\}\} = \Big\{\{a,\{a,b\}\},\{\{a,\{a,b\}\},c\}\Big\}$$
Wich clearly shows why $((a,b),c) \ne (a,b,c)$.

Comment: You didn't give a definition for $(a,b,c)$...

Comment: think he did, with a∈A,b∈B,c∈C, saying each is a member of a set

Comment: yeah cause if you compare relative positioning(order pair result), a tuple(ordered collection) is not the same as a single element.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes, but since there is a definition for $A\times B$ in the question, it would be reasonable to include the definition of $A\times B\times C$ ;)

Comment: Well, if you use $(a,b,c)$ as an primitive object, sure, it makes sense.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I've added some definitions you may like :P

Comment: Wait why can (a,b) be written as {a, {a,b}}?

Comment: and how is ((a,b),c) and (a,b,c) of 1-1 correspondence?

Comment: @committedandroider 1.: Given a set of the structure $\{a,\{a,b\}\}$ you can uniquely tell $a$ and $b$ apart and know their order in the pair $(a,b)$. 2.: You just gave the correspondence (i.e. the bijection): An element $(a,b,c)$ corresponds to the element $((a,b),c)$.

Comment: but (a,b) is a coordinate point defined by two integers while (a,{a,b}) is a coordinate point defined by an integer and a set.

Comment: Oh I get 1 to 1 correspondence, onto and one to one. Thankfully theres just the eye test for this, no mathematical expression :)

Comment: @committedandroider Read closely: $\{a,\{a,b\}\}$ is a _set_ with two elements. A rigorous construction of ordered pairs can be made using this set, much like the construction of the natural numbers as $0 = \emptyset, n + 1 = n \cup \{n\}$

Comment: yeah I get that, its two elements are an integer,a, and a set, {a,b}. So from that same reasoning (x,y) is the same as {x, {x,y}}?

Comment: @committedandroider Yes. It works with arbitrary objects ($a$ and $b$ could even be sets).

Comment: 0=∅, 0 is the empty set?

Comment: @committedandroider Look up [Set-theoretic construction of the natural numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_definition_of_natural_numbers) ;)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: What does a typical element of $(A \times B) \times C$ look like? A typical element of $A \times B \times C$?

> A typical element of the former is $((a, b), c)$, which in particular is an ordered pair, and a typical element of the latter is $(a, b, c)$, which is an ordered triple.
> Still, as you point out, these sets are very similar, and in fact there is a canonical bijection between them, namely $$((a, b), c) \leftrightarrow (a, b, c).$$

Comment: that canonical bijection might be a bit overkill for a beginner like me haha

Comment: Hi, i maybe way late here, but how do you prove the canonical bijection part? Any references to where this is proved?